# Do we need a [client] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There's this new question from today:

[Why don't event photographers release non-touched up images?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73378/35348)

At the moment it's only tagged with [wedding](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding). While being related to [wedding](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wedding), this question generalises to [event-photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-photography) or any kind of photography where delivery of unedited files is a possible client requirement.

It's about the relationship between the client and the photographer. I was surprised that there's no [client](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client), [clients](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clients), [customer-relations](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customer-relations) or similar tag.

[A search for "client"](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=client) reveals a few questions related to clients that would all benefit from being unified with a tag like this.

There are [business](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business), [contracts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) and [professional](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional) that are related, but there's no overall tag like in other categories, like [flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flash) or [lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lens) for example. Should there be such a tag? Or are the mentioned related tags sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question certainly needed more/better tags, but I think the [business](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) and [event-photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event-photography) tags you added should be sufficient to help someone interested in photographers' clients find the question. How likely is it that someone would be interested in client relationships, but not business or weddings or event photography? How many questions would be tagged [client](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client) but not [business](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business)?

It's important to have a set of tags that are meaningful, but it's also important to keep the set small enough to be manageable and to avoid too much overlap between tags. We [currently have 1090 tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/photo/query/329416/how-many-tags-are-there), and although that's far fewer than [some other sites](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/329416/how-many-tags-are-there), it still seems like more than most Photos.SE users are probably able to use effectively.

**For those reasons, I don't think a [client](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/client) tag is needed.**

Comment: And if we ever needed to, we could always make client a synonym of business, if client is a high profile search term.